# Language Translator with jquery.localize

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a website and using jquery 3 and jquery.localize file for translation from English to Urdu using code. When I refresh the page (Refresh Necessary), the page shows its default language. I want to stuck it to selected language like if I selected Urdu then after refreshing the page must show in Urdu. Help be with this....Please
Here is The Language File and JavaScript function:

```
<script>
var en = true;
function myFunction() {
if (en) {
$('[data-localize]').localize('mylanguage', { language: 'ur' });
en = false;
}else {
var $elements = $('[data-localize]');
$.each($elements, function (i, value) {
  $elements.eq(i).html($elements.eq(i).attr('data-localize'));
});

en = true;
}
}
</script>
```

here is [image: picture] of json file.

and Here is Code which helps to change language.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should save the user chosen language and use it every time you load the page.
Usually, variables in JavaScript are temporary, and every time you refresh the page all variables became `undefined` until you use or define them.

You can save the language into `localStorage`. Those kinds of "variables" are saved between refresh. For example:

```
 // Set Variable:
 localStorage.userLanguage='en'

 // Get Variable:
 alert(localStorage.userLanguage)
```

You can use the `localStorage` object to keep the user language when navigating on refreshing the page.

#### Read More:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: How to use this in if else statement....??? If I change language then after refresh the page, it should be in selected language, not in default language.